# How to list numbers of things

Tags: grammar, counters, quantifiers

Where do you place the counter in Japanese when you want to specify how many of something there are, especially if you're listing multiple things?

I believe the counter usually goes after the particle associated with the noun:

> I bought 3 pencils => 私は鉛筆{えんぴつ}を三本{さんぼん}買{か}いました。

But what do you do when there are multiple things you want to count? Are these sentences correct?

> I bought two books and three pencils. => 私は本{ほん}を二冊{にさつ}と鉛筆{えんぴつ}を三本{さんぼん}買{か}いました。 ?
>
> Two books and three pencils are on the desk. => 本{ほん}が二冊{にさつ}と鉛筆{えんぴつ}が三本{さんぼん}机{つくえ}の上{うえ}にあります。

Can you use the の particle to mean the same thing? Would it change the meaning or nuance?

> 私は二冊{にさつ}の本{ほん}と三本{さんぼん}の鉛筆{えんぴつ}を買{か}いました。 ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In basically all informal daily conversations, the most natural way to express the numbers and items is:

> Name of item + (particle) + number + counter + verb phrase

Natural: 「ビッグマック + を + **ふたつ** + [食]{た}べた。」 = "I ate two Big Macs."

Natural: 「みそラーメン +を + **よっつ** + [下]{くだ}さい。」 = "(Give us) four miso-ramens, please!"

Not very natural though grammatical: 「**ふたつの**ビッグマックを食べた。」 & 「**よっつの**みそラーメンを下さい。」

**What this means is that in Japanese, "number + counter" is most often used adverbially, modifying the verb that follows.**

The not-so-natural versions will be understood by virtually all native speakers, but you will definitely sound foreign if you say those, ***using the quantity adjectivally as in English***.

When you have to express an action involving a list of mutiple things, simply  place them one by one.

> 「ビール（を）2本（と）、ラーメン（を）よっつ（と）、ギョウザ（を）みっつ下さい。」

= "Can we have 2 bottles of beer, 4 orders of ramen and 3 orders of pot stickers, please?"

In informal conversation at eateries, these particles in parentheses above are often omitted.

Finally, even though using the "number + counter + の + item name" is unnatural in everyday conversations as I stated above, it is used in literature, legal papers, business communication, etc. when the number needs to be emphasized for a reason.