# Listing two different object

Tags: grammar

I encounter this question in my problem set.

> Reizoko ni kudamono ____ (_____) _____ _____ ga  arimasu
>
> 1. ga    2. mittsu  3. to   4. gyuunyuu

I see in the solution that the answer for word in parentheses is (2. mittsu).
What is the complete sentence? What is the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: You are asking for the complete solution? What is your attempt?

Comment: Did you mean "listing two different *subjects*"?

Comment: `1. ga 2. mittsu 3. to 4. gyuunyuu` ← もうできてるやん・・

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct sentence is:

> 冷蔵庫に果物が3つと牛乳があります。
>   Reizoko ni kudamono ga mittsu to gyunyu ga arimasu.

Which means "There are three pieces of fruit and milk in the fridge."

To correctly answer this question, you need to know:

- How to use と (*to*) to list two or more nouns
- [Two ways to count things](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17816/5010) and how to use it in combination with と
- 果物 is always "countable" with つ/個 (*tsu/ko*), while 牛乳 is not counted like this.

Comment: Do you know where I can find/read a list of things with their correct counter? Like the 牛乳 how did you know that it us not counted as つ? Is it because it is liquid? I initially thought つ can be applied because it is milk in a box?  Thank you~