# Meaning of と in "Quantifier plus と"

Tags: particle-と

I failed to understand the meaning of と in the sentence "峠を二つ三つ**と**こえても、まだ海は見えてこない" when I read the story [あの坂をのぼれば](http://blog.livedoor.jp/natsuhanamiyazaki/archives/40638060.html).

I browsed through the meanings of と in 明鏡国語辞典, but it seems none of them fits.

Could you tell me the meaning of this と and share some examples of this sort of と?

Answer (score 3):

> 「峠{とうげ}を二{ふた}つ三{みっ}つ**と**こえても、まだ海{うみ}は見{み}えてこない。」

こえる＝越える

First and foremost, quantifiers are often used ***adverbially*** in Japanese whereas they are more often used ***adjectivally*** in English.  This has been discussed [in this Q&A](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/how-to-list-numbers-of-things/17832#17832).

Japanese way: 「峠を二つ三つ（と）こえる」、「ハンバーガーを二つ食{た}べる」、「テーブルにリンゴが２個{こ}ある。」, etc.

"English" way: 「二つ三つ**の**峠をこえる」、「二つのハンバーガーを食べる」、「テーブルに２個のリンゴがある。」, etc.

In the sentence in question, 「二つ三つと」 functions adverbially to modify the verb 「こえて（も）」.

There is virtually no difference in meaning between 「二つ三つ**と**」 and 「二つ三つ」.  Both function adverbially and both mean "***a few (times)***".

The 「と」 simply adds a very small amount of emphasis to the quantifier/adverb.  Likewise, the difference in meaning between 「ゆっくり」 and 「ゆっくりと」, 「しっかり」 and 「しっかりと」, etc. is minimal.