# How to say "There are two of each"?

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese, counters

Say I have 8 tea bags, and there are two of each type of tea bag; 2 early gray, 2 mint tea, ... . How can I say "there are two of each (kind)"?

Comment: Welcome to JLSE. As a rule, all questioners are expected to provide some translation attempt or research effort. Otherwise your question may [get closed as "mere translation request"](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/5010) by someone who doesn't want to learn Japanese. Please keep this in mind next time.

Comment: Welcome @A. Mashreghi! Ideally in a question here, you'd provide some of your guesses as to the correct answer to get us started. However, I acknowledge this is a particularly hard construction for learners to translate initially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say いろいろな種類(のティーバッグ)が2個ずつあります.

いろいろな種類 can work as a noun meaning "things of various kinds".

This 2個ずつ is an [adverb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17816/5010), and ずつ is a useful suffix that means "for every" or "each". In case you don't know ずつ, here's a good starter:  [JLPT N3 Grammar ずつ (zutsu)](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%9A%E3%81%A4-zutsu-meaning/)