# Am I understanding this 遭遇 correctly?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, syntax

> オートバランサは一瞬だけ装着者の動作を遅らせると言われている。人間より遙かに計算速度が速い機械がやることだ。普通の人間では気づかぬほんのわずかな時間である。
>
> だが、その一瞬が戦場では生死の境を分けることがある。
>
> 一万人のジャケット兵が参加する作戦を三回やって、とびきり運の悪い奴がひとり遭遇するかしないかの確率であろうとも、もしかしたら女神に見放された運の悪い奴に自分がなってしまう可能性がある。目の前にギタイが迫ってからオートバランサに愚痴を言ってもはじまらないのだ。だから、戦闘が始まると、古兵のフェレウはオートバランサのスイッチを切る。

Here, the main character talks about a function in his full armor body shield called "auto balancer" which for a very brief moment delays the action of the wearer of the shield.

Now here comes the part that I do not understand: in the following paragraph, it says that in three operations each involving 10,000 jackets (shield), the possibility of encountering a very unlucky fellow may not amount even to one person, but there is a possibility that anyone might find themselves in that situation, thus some old fighters switch it off.

What I do not understand is how the official translation translates this as:

> In three full battles of ten thousand Jackets each, only one soldier might have the misfortune of encountering a problem with the auto-balancer, and if the auto-balancer decides to hiccup right when you’ve got a Mimic bearing down on you, it’s all over. It’s a slight chance, but no one wants to be the unlucky bastard who draws the short straw.

Here, 遭遇 refers to encountering an unlucky fellow not being a problem, as far as I can see or am I wrong? I feel the author was vague as he did not specify what he was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The implied target of 遭遇 here is not a person but an extremely rare/unlucky event (不運 or 不幸な出来事).

> 一万人のジャケット兵が参加する作戦を三回やって、とびきり運の悪い奴がひとり **(不運に)** 遭遇するかしないかの確率であろうとも
>
> [literally] Even if it's a (small) chance of whether or not one incredibly unlucky person will encounter **(such a misfortune)** after conducting three operations where 10,000 jacketed soldiers participate, ...
>
> → The odds would be so low that no one might **have such bad luck** even after conducting three operations with 10,000 jacketed soldiers, but ...

Comment: @user50156 One (unspecified) solider.

Comment: So is this 不運 the 一瞬だけ装着者の動作を遅らせる

Comment: @user50156 No, this 不運 refers to some extremely rare event that can kill a soldier due to the auto balancer.

Comment: Can I ask why 遭遇 does not refer to the observer as in we could barearly find one guy in 10000 soilder

Comment: @user50156 AがB**に**遭遇する means "A encounters B". Note that 遭遇する is **intransitive** and B must be marked with に. **ひとり is not marked with に**, so it's an [adverbial quantifier](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17816/5010) that describes **the number of the subject**. Therefore, even when there's no other context, とびきり運の悪い奴がひとり遭遇する always means "(only) one incredibly unlucky person encounters [it/this/something]" rather than "an incredibly unlucky person encounters one person". Likewise, 男が3人見ている normally means "three men are watching [me/it]", not "a man is watching three people".

Comment: So another less literal translation would be "Even if this is something no one might encounter after 10,000 jacketed soldiers participated in three operations, I myself might end up being the first unlucky person abandoned by the goddess".